# Como usar la informacion que esta dentro de un pipe en C?

Tags: c

Tengo un programa que crea un proceso pid con fork() y en el hijo hace dup2 para que lo que me imprima por pantalla lo pase a pipeA

```
            dup2(pipeA[1],1);
            leer(archivos[j],substring);
```

Leer me imprime strings de caracteres y con el dup2 me almacena esos strings en el pipeA, quiero guardar la informacion que esta en el pipe en un buffer para eso uso:

```
bytes=read(pipeA[0],buffer,BUFFER_TAM);
```

Antes ya habia inicializado mi pipe con:

```
if (pipe(pipeA) == -1) {
    perror("bad pipe1");
    exit(1);
}
```

Cuando copilo en la terminal de linux no hay errores pero se queda pegado y para volver a usar la terminal tengo que usar "ctrl c". El error creo que esta en el read ya que si lo quito no se me queda pegado y termina pero no puedo usar la informacion del pipe, en caso de que el error esta aqui como ¿Si no es con read como leo el pipe?. ¿No se si el pipe es el error, y si se lee los pipes con read?

Comment: Utilizas `pipeA[1]` y `pipeA[0]` para hacer referencia a la misma pipe?

Comment: No logro ver ningún problema con el poco código que muestras y lo que explicas, tal vez con mas código podamos encontrar el error, tal vez tu error ni siquiera este en el IPC (pipe) si tienes dudas de como funciona `pipe` utilizando `dup` aquí hay un ejemplo fácil http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642732/using-dup2-for-piping